# Update database after feeds' import

Tags: database, feeds, location

Hello Drupal community,

I'm trying to develop a customized module that updates the database with some operations on some fields (geocoding an adress field) after an import using feeds. Any idea which hook I should use?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another way to alter the feed import.
while importing, feeds uses to node functions : hook_node_save() and hook_node_presave(). Instead of using feeds' hook i used hook_node_presave() which alter the query before it is executed.

Works good for me !

Answer (score 0):

There is a [hook_feeds_after_import](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!feeds!feeds.api.php/function/hook_feeds_after_import/7) for this

Comment: Do you know how can i debug it ? I can't see any variable using either dpm(), kpr() or var_dump().

Comment: You can debug using watchdog function